# Logar no portal NFe com cURL e PHP

Tags: php, libcurl, nfe

Já pesquisei muito sobre isso e até agora não consegui fazer nada concreto. Será que isso é possível?

Quero fazer um formulario com o campo chave de acesso e o codigo captcha para ser preenchido. logo será enviado esses dados para o portal nfe e me retornará as informações da nfe.

Com isso ocorre o erro de sessão expirada.

index.php

Documento sem título

```
<body> 
    <?php

    function recebe_imagem($url, $arquivo, $cookief = "", $cookiej = "") {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        /* if(!empty($cookief)) { 
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
          }
          if(!empty($cookiej)) {
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, "cookie.txt");
          } */
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0)");

        //curl_setopt($ch, , 
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        //curl_close ($ch); 
        $fp = fopen($arquivo, 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $data);
        fclose($fp);
        return $arquivo;
    }
    ?> 
    <?php
    $img = recebe_imagem("http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/scripts/srf/intercepta/captcha.aspx?opt=image ", "receita.gif", "", "receita.txt");
    ?> 
    <img src="receita.gif" /> 
    <form method="POST" action="consulta.php"> 
        captcha 
        <input name='letras' maxlength='4' size='8' /> 
        <br /> 
        codigo acesso 
        <input name='cnpj' maxlength='44' size='60' /> 
        <input type="submit" /> 
    </form> 
</body>
```

consulta.php

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>Documento sem título</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <?php
    $cnpj = $_POST['cnpj'];
    $letras = $_POST['letras'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ContentPlaceHolder1$txtChaveAcessoCompleta=$cnpj&ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCaptcha=$letras&ContentPlaceHolder1$btnConsultar=Continuar");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consulta.aspx?tipoConsulta=completa&tipoConteudo=XbSeqxE8pl8= ");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consultaCompleta.aspx?tipoConteudo=XbSeqxE8pl8= ");
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    echo utf8_encode($output);
    ?> 
</body>
```

Existe algum script para executar isso de forma melhor?

Answer (score 3):

Se a sessão estiver expirando, então provavelmente existem mais parâmetros a serem passados para:

```
http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consultaCompleta.aspx?tipoConteudo=XbSeqxE8pl8=
```

Utilize algum [debugger](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) para checar quais parâmetros a requisição solicita. Baseada neles, envie-os.

*Não consigo testar aqui porque não tenho nenhum número de NF-e válido.*

Comment: valew, o sistema está rodando aqui para teste> http://www.meifacil.com.br/system/estudo/nfe/
codigo de acesso para teste> 33110733068883000201550010115687931122936510

se puder me ajudar e testar agradeço muito.

Answer (score 1):

Não trabalho com `PHP` e o que sei sobre ele é muito pouco e insuficiente para ajudar.
Muito menos então sei sobre `cURL` e se o que tenho para passar para você é realmente necessário.

Porém eu já fiz um acesso ao Portal com `Delphi` e tive que incluir vários campos no ***post*** para então conseguir acessar a página, pois o Portal é feito em `ASP.NET WebForms` e isso inclui vários controles.

Tem uma pergunta no ***SOen*** que fala sobre esse acesso e tem esses campos: **[idhttp-idcookiemanager-asp-net-webform-page-close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216503/idhttp-idcookiemanager-asp-net-webform-page-close)**. É com o `Delphi`.

Essa é uma lista dos campos que creio serem necessários incluir no ***post***:

```
__VIEWSTATE
__EVENTVALIDATION
__EVENTTARGET
__EVENTARGUMENT
ctl00$txtPalavraChave
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtChaveAcessoCompleta
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCaptcha
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnConsultar=Continuar
hiddenInputToUpdateATBuffer_CommonToolkitScripts=1
```

Os valores de `__VIEWSTATE`, `__EVENTVALIDATION` e os demais estão em ***inputs*** do tipo ***hidden***. Você precisa passar esses valores, claro.

[image: input´s hidden]

Essa é uma demonstração do código pelas ferramentas de desenvolvimento do Google Chrome.
Os outros campos estão no formulário.

Bom, está ai meus dois centavos sobre o assunto.
Espero que possa lhe ajudar.

Comment: Muito obrigado mais como consigo os valores desses campos:
__VIEWSTATE
__EVENTVALIDATION
__EVENTTARGET
__EVENTARGUMENT
ctl00$txtPalavraChave

Sabe me dizer?

Comment: Valew a ajuda mais vou precisar pagar pelo serviço pois não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Caso tenha alguém para indicar agradeço.