# Consultar NFe sem certificado

Tags: nfe

Existe alguma forma de consultar a base de NFe sem certificado via programação?

Hoje precisaria somente consultar quais os produtos estão na NFe para automatizar um processo interno.

Comment: Sua pergunta está um bocado ampla. Aqui tem um ponto de partida http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15166/logar-no-portal-nfe-com-curl-e-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem sim eduardo, você pode usar qualquer cliente http para consultar a página de consulta da NFe, e baixar o contéudo da mesma para uma string, daí você monta o documento traduzindo as tags html para os campos conforme o leiaute da NFe, o único chato é o captcha que ou você contorna ou exiba no seu programa para o usuário digitar, a desvantagem disso é que você codifica em função da página da sefaz, mas é bem simples de implementar.

Comment: Entendi. Isso é legal em termos legislativos?

Comment: @EduardoCarísio, sim isso é legal, pois o site é público para qualquer um consultar, mas você precisa ter a chave das notas.